# How do I use YOLOv5 without the internet for kaggle competition

Tags: python, kaggle, yolov5

I am attempting to use a software called YOLOv5 in my python code for a Kaggle competition. The only thing is it requires you not to use the internet. I have the yolov5 file already loaded into the kaggle code. but am unsure how to call in in my code.

I've tried loading it in the following way but keep getting errors.
[image: Kaggle data]

```
import torch
torch.save('yolov5x6.pt', 'yolov5')
yolov5x6_model = torch.load('yolov5')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yolov5 is a follow up version of yolo which is a neural network library in c language, also known as Darknet created by pjreddie.

It is an object detector model which can be trained to recognise objects in images or videos.

If you just want to detect some daily life object then you can just run inference on images/videos using python and trained weights and config file. You will find these files under the pretrained checkpoints section at the following link.
https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5